# How to deploy multiples csv files in azure table storage at a time using powershell script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-table-storage

I have opened the new thread as requested.I believe you have the script with you which I shared in the previous forum.Please consider that script and find the below requirement.

```
function Add-Entity()
{
 [CmdletBinding()]

 param
 (
 $table, 
 [string] $partitionKey, 
 [string] $RowKey, 
 [string] $Label_Value,
 [string] $Lable_cost 
 )

 $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $partitionKey, $rowKey 
 $entity.Properties.Add("Label_Value",$Label_Value)
 $entity.Properties.Add("Label_Value",$Lable_cost)
 $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
}

$tableName = "TestTable"
$subscriptionName = "Tech Enabled Solutions"
$resourceGroupName = "abc"
$storageAccountName = "defghi"
$location = "North Central US, South Central US"

# Get the storage key for the storage account
$StorageAccountKey = "12345678"

# Get a storage context
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

# Get a reference to the table
$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx -ErrorAction Ignore
$csv = Import-CSV "d:\a\1\s\DeploymentScripts\TestTable.csv"

ForEach ($line in $csv)
{
 Add-Entity -Table $table -partitionKey $line.partitionkey -rowKey $line.RowKey -Label_Value $line.Label_Value Lable_cost $line.Lable_cost

}
```

My assumption is like,if I can pass files as a parameters in the script and it will read that file and can insert and delete the data for that particular file into azure storage.but the thing is currently I am inserting data using this command in the power shell script...

$csv = Import-CSV "d:\a\1\s\DeploymentScripts\TestTable.csv" currently as per the script it is testtable.csv

if I want to pass different file say like testtable2.csv to the powershell script,I can't write 2nd script and keep in VSTS repo right as there are many csv files I need to deploy into azure storage.so at the run time of script how can I pass different files using one script which i am currently running. how can I implement the script and how can I pass parameters.

One more doubt pal, how can I deploy multiple csv files into table storage as each csv file data is different in rows and columns and will have extra rows and extra columns for each csv file.So how can I automate/implement/change the above script for deploying multiple csv files using power shell script as not every csv file having same columns right,some may csv files have 3 fields and some csv files have 5,6,7 and so on fields..I hope you understand my requirement.Please help me out.

Comment: Please share those scripts in this post as it will be hard to find it otherwise. A full example of what you tried and where you failed would be useful.

Comment: function Add-Entity()
{
 [CmdletBinding()]

 param
 (
 $table, 
 [string] $partitionKey, 
 [string] $RowKey, 
 [string] $Label_Value,
 [string] $Lable_cost 
 ) $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $partitionKey, $rowKey 
 $entity.Properties.Add("Label_Value",$Label_Value)
 $entity.Properties.Add("Label_Value",$Lable_cost)
 $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
}

Comment: Add that to your question as correctly formatted code. It's really hard to read that.

Comment: $tableName = "TestTable"
$subscriptionName = "Tech Enabled Solutions"
$resourceGroupName = "abc"
$storageAccountName = "efghigh"
$location = "North Central US"
# Get the storage key for the storage account
$StorageAccountKey = "12345678"
# Get a storage context
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

# Get a reference to the table
$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx -ErrorAction Ignore
$csv = Import-CSV "d:\a\1\s\DeploymentScripts\TestTable.csv"

Comment: ForEach ($line in $csv)
{
 Add-Entity -Table $table -partitionKey $line.partitionkey -rowKey $line.RowKey -Label_Value $line.Label_Value Lable_cost $line.Lable_cost
}    This is my complete code..So please help pal.

Comment: I Will add it to question.

Comment: I have posted to the script below to the answer as I am not aware of how to list all this code into a question.

Comment: I added the script to your question. Maybe you can adjust your question accordingly, so that it becomes easy to understand where exactly your problem is. Maybe some error output would be great.

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Comment: Not yet MSFT. I Will update you once my issue is resolved.I am still working on this request.Kindly wait for some time.i will update you on this by tomorrow.Still I am confusing at the for loop whether I can keep in my script or not as this for loop in the script I shared is adding 4 columns but if I want to add 6 columns do I need to add the 2 column names as well in the script.if yes,different csv files has different fields names and we can't add those columns names in for loop right.or let me know if I can remove the foreach statement code in my script.

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN Which 4 columns? You just need to specify the columns in arguments (e.g. c1,c2 in my script) You need to do update data for each iteration of csv files, the next iteration isn't related to previous iteration.

Comment: You have shared one script right so how can I relate that script with my script.My requirement is like,I have 4 columns say c1,c2,c3,c4 in testtable1.csv file and 6 columns say c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10 in testtable2.csv  file.So How to deploy these 2 csv files with different columns in each table.This is my exact requirement.I have 12 csv files so how to automate the script and please tell me which scripts I can include and can relate as I am not having idea how to combine the below 2 scripts( one I shared one you shared).Kindly cooperate  on this.

Comment: ForEach ($line in $csv)
{
 Add-Entity -Table $table -partitionKey $line.partitionkey -rowKey $line.RowKey -Label_Value $line.Label_Value Lable_cost $line.Lable_cost
} Suppose in this script I have added 4 columns and if I want to deploy different csv file of different columns( 6 columns) then how can I make this script .Should I need to add those 6 columns in the above for loop.if yes, if I deploy first csv file then its having 4 columns then output will throw error as its can't find other 2 columns.

Comment: Hi MSFT, Kindly update me on the below request which I requested yesterday please as I have updated my script which is succeeded but not adding any data into tables.

Comment: @MSFT, I am using the above script for now in my project.Now, I want to deploy the same csv file into multiple environments.So for each environment my subscription name ,acc name,storage key details will be varied .So how can I pass those details into the one script.Please help me.

Comment: Any update on this please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding pass file path as parameter, you can definition the global parameters for this Script:

```
param(
[string]$filepath
)
function Add-Entity()
{
 [CmdletBinding()]

 param
 (
 $table, 
 [string] $partitionKey, 
 [string] $RowKey, 
 [string] $Label_Value,
 [string] $Lable_cost 
 )

 $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $partitionKey, $rowKey 
 $entity.Properties.Add("Label_Value",$Label_Value)
 $entity.Properties.Add("Label_Value",$Lable_cost)
 $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
}

$tableName = "TestTable"
$subscriptionName = "Tech Enabled Solutions"
$resourceGroupName = "abc"
$storageAccountName = "defghi"
$location = "North Central US, South Central US"

# Get the storage key for the storage account
$StorageAccountKey = "12345678"

# Get a storage context
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

# Get a reference to the table
$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx -ErrorAction Ignore
$csv = Import-CSV $filepath

ForEach ($line in $csv)
{
 Add-Entity -Table $table -partitionKey $line.partitionkey -rowKey $line.RowKey -Label_Value $line.Label_Value Lable_cost $line.Lable_cost

}
```

Then you can pass parameters in Script Arguments input box of Azure PowerShell task: `-filepath $(build.sourcesdirectory)\DeploymentScripts\TestTable.csv`.

Regarding the multiple files with different columns, you can define a array object parameter, then include filepath and columns in its properties, then iterate the array object, for example:

```
    param(
         [object[]]$fileObj
        )
    foreach($fo in $fileObj){

     Write-Host $fo.filepath

    $cArray=$fo.Cols.split(",")

      foreach($c in $cArray){

      Write-Host $c

      #TODO add column to table

     }

#TODO insert data to cloud table per to current file 
    }
```

arguments:

```
-fileObj @(@{"filepath"="$(build.sourcesdirectory)\DeploymentScripts\TestTable.csv";"Cols"='c1,c2'},@{"filepath"="$(build.sourcesdirectory)\DeploymentScripts\TestTable2.csv";"Cols"='c3,c2'})
```

Update:

```
foreach($fo in $fileObj){
 Write-Host $fo.filepath
 $csv = Import-CSV $fo.filepath
  $cArray=$fo.Cols.split(",")
  foreach($line in $csv)
    {
    Write-Host "$($line.partitionkey), $($line.rowKey)"
    $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $line.partitionkey, $line.rowKey 
        foreach($c in $cArray){
     Write-Host "$c,$($line.$c)"
 $entity.Properties.Add($c,$line.$c)


        }
 $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
 }
}
```

Argument:

```
@(@{"filepath"="data.csv";"Cols"="Col1,Col2,Col3"},@{"filepath"="data2.csv";"Cols"="Col1,Col6,Col7,Col8"})
```

Sample data in csv:

data.csv:

```
 partitionkey,rowKey,Col1,Col2,Col3
    p1,r1,one,two,three
    p2,r2,example1,example2,example3
```

data2.csv:

```
partitionkey,rowKey,Col1,Col6,Col7,Col8
p1,r1,one,two,three,four
p2,r2,example1,example2,example3,example4
```

Update:

```
param(
     [object[]]$fileObj
    )

$storageAccountName = "XXX"

$tableName="XXX"

# Get the storage key for the storage account
$StorageAccountKey = "XXX"

# Get a storage context
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx -ErrorAction Ignore

foreach($fo in $fileObj){
 Write-Host $fo.filepath
 $csv = Import-CSV $fo.filepath
  $cArray=$fo.Cols.split(",")
  foreach($line in $csv)
    {
    Write-Host "$($line.partitionkey), $($line.rowKey)"
    $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $line.partitionkey, $line.rowKey 
        foreach($c in $cArray){
     Write-Host "$c,$($line.$c)"
        $entity.Properties.Add($c,$line.$c)


        }
        $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
 }
}
```

Update:

```
param(
     [object[]]$fileObj
    )

$storageAccountName = "XXX"

$tableName="XXX"

# Get the storage key for the storage account
$StorageAccountKey = "XXX"

# Get a storage context
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey



foreach($fo in $fileObj){
$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $fo.tableName -Context $ctx -ErrorAction Ignore
 Write-Host $fo.filepath
 $csv = Import-CSV $fo.filepath
  $cArray=$fo.Cols.split(",")
  foreach($line in $csv)
    {
    Write-Host "$($line.partitionkey), $($line.rowKey)"
    $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $line.partitionkey, $line.rowKey 
        foreach($c in $cArray){
     Write-Host "$c,$($line.$c)"
        $entity.Properties.Add($c,$line.$c)


        }
        $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
 }
}
```

Arguments: `@(@{"filepath"="data.csv";"Cols"="Col1,Col2,Col3";"tableName"="table1"},@{"filepath"="data2.csv";"Cols"="Col1,Col6,Col7,Col8";"tableName"="table2"})`

Comment: I am running the below script only along with the parameters you shared but throwing error:2017-10-24T09:45:01.8482070Z ##[command]. 'd:\a\1\s\DeploymentScripts\InsertEntity.ps1' -fileObj @(@{"filepath"="d:\a\1\s\DeploymentScripts\TestTable.csv";"Cols"='partitionkey,rowkey,Lable_value'},@{"filepath"="d:\a\1\s\DeploymentScripts\TestTable2.csv";"Cols"='partitionkey,rowkey,Lable_value,Lable_cost'})
2017-10-24T09:45:02.4312066Z d:\a\1\s\DeploymentScripts\TestTable.csv
2017-10-24T09:45:02.4372069Z partitionkey
2017-10-24T09:45:02.4382085Z rowkey
2017-10-24T09:45:02.4382085Z Lable_value

Comment: 2017-10-24T09:45:02.4392062Z d:\a\1\s\DeploymentScripts\TestTable2.csv
2017-10-24T09:45:02.4392062Z partitionkey
2017-10-24T09:45:02.4392062Z rowkey
2017-10-24T09:45:02.4402069Z Lable_value
2017-10-24T09:45:02.4413537Z Lable_cost
2017-10-24T09:45:03.6140905Z ##[error]Import-CSV : Could not find file 'D:\a\1\s\filepath'.
At D:\a\1\s\DeploymentScripts\InsertEntity.ps1:33 char:8
+ $csv = Import-CSV filepath
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Import-Csv], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN Sorry for the mistake in my first part code, updated it (Add $). What's your current script?

Comment: Hi MSFT, I would like to deploy multiple csv files with different columns in each csv file.So please suggest me how many scripts i need to execute and share those scripts kindly.because the whole post is bit confusing friend.So please please don't mind and try to help me.As I asked  you how to deploy multiple csv files and I understand that we can deploy by passing $filename as a parameter but how about the columns define in the script.

Comment: currently  I have added 4 columns in testtable1.csv file:say partitionkey,ro‌​wkey,Lable_value,Lab‌​le_cost' but how to define other csv files columns in this script say partitionkey,rowkey,price,validity and there would be many columns which we can't define right in the script.or how to add all the columns of different csv files of different columns into table storage.

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN I updated my answer with sample code, you can try it.

Comment: Hi Pal,Could you please help me out on my request.

Comment: What's the problem now?

Comment: I have run your script,its not throwing any error it is succeeding but at the same time its not adding any data into tables.I have posted my script above..Please check that.

Comment: Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: Share the detail build log and the newest script on the OneDrive.

Comment: Where can I find the one drive path.I am new to stack .Kindly tell me where can I share that script.

Comment: Can you please share the path so that i will upload the script and the build log?

Comment: Refer to this article to share files: [Share OneDrive files and folders](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-OneDrive-files-and-folders-9fcc2f7d-de0c-4cec-93b0-a82024800c07?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Can I have your email ID so that I will share immediately. By the way I have uploaded the scripts in onedrive: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhnyl5XKnhGWiHXYY..Please have a look.

Comment: Hi MSFT, Please find my script at this location : https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhnyl5XKnhGWiHXYY and help me out as it is high in priority to my team.Hope you understood.

Comment: On the other hand, set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share the build log if the issue still persist.

Comment: Hi msft, may I know where you have updated the script? In one drive or above?, please let me know.

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN I added the new code to the answer (bottom)

Comment: Hi msft, can you please share the link where exactly you added the new code as I am unable to find.

Comment: Hi MSF, Thanks for your help.Will you let me know,what is the best way to do table storage deployment as my dev team is asking like that they have many times of which each table is having thousands of entries.So our script will delete all the entries and inserting everything again.But that shouldn't be done.Hence,they are asking me to consult any microsoft team or blog people to check the best way to do table storage deployment.Do you have idea how we can do as the scripts will be doing depleting and inserting thousand of entries everything.

Comment: do we have any delta approach like it will first check all the tables entries and if existed then it should just append the newly added entries which are being added into the csv files by dev team those entries only we need to update into table storage.that's it.this is one approach.Do you have any best possible approach.Please kindly help me.

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN Don't know the better way, but you can open a new thread and discuss it in a new thread.

Comment: Thanks MSFT for your kind help.

Comment: Hi MSFT, The link which you have given has many scripts updated.not able to find the latest update .Kindly help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46847351/revisions.How to find the latest code as I can see latest code edited on 31st Oct.Is that the latest one?

Comment: Yes, it is the latest one.

Comment: But that code is only for one table right I want to deploy multiple tables right.in your script you mentioned tablename=xxx  i can give one table but if I want to pass multiple how the script can be?

Comment: This is the updated code as per your confirmation.                          
  param(
     [object[]]$fileObj
    )

$storageAccountName = "XXX"

$tableName="XXX"

# Get the storage key for the storage account
$StorageAccountKey = "XXX"

# Get a storage context
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx -ErrorAction Ignore

foreach($fo in $fileObj){
 Write-Host $fo.filepath
 $csv = Import-CSV $fo.filepath
  $cArray=$fo.Cols.split(",")

Comment: foreach($line in $csv)
    {
    Write-Host "$($line.partitionkey), $($line.rowKey)"
    $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $line.partitionkey, $line.rowKey 
        foreach($c in $cArray){
     Write-Host "$c,$($line.$c)"
        $entity.Properties.Add($c,$line.$c)


        }
        $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
 }
}

Comment: Check the latest Update.

Comment: The issue has been solved in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091334/best-approach-to-deploy-tables-into-table-storage/47129050?noredirect=1#comment81481288_47129050, you can accept this solution as answer.

Comment: Yes,That has been solved but I need to deploy multiple tables right.That is not yet fixed.I could able to deploy only one csv file data not multiple csv files at a time.Please let me know whether I can accept that as answer or not ?

Comment: Will you help me in future if I need help on multiple tables deployment into table storage ?

Comment: I mean accept the solution of this thread as answer, not another one. Regarding multiple table issue, we can discuss it in that thread.