# Best approach to deploy tables into table storage

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-table-storage

Will you let me know,what is the best way to do table storage deployment as my dev team is asking like that they have many tables of which each table is having thousands of entries.Hence,they are asking me to consult any microsoft team or blog people to check the best way to do table storage deployment.Do you have idea how we can do as the scripts will be doing depleting and inserting thousand of entries everytime.

do we have any delta approach like it will first check all the tables entries and if existed then it should just append the newly added entries which are being added into the csv files by dev team those entries only we need to update into table storage.that's it.this is one approach.Do you have any best possible approach.Please kindly help me.

Comment: I have many csv files ,each csv file consists of thousand of table entries.Please let me know how to deploy those csv files into table storage through VSTS.I don't find any plugin /task in VSTS.Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **InsertOrReplace(ITableEntity)** method in [TableBatchOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablebatchoperation?view=azure-dotnet) Class that can do batch operation with **ExecuteBatch** method, try it with this code:

```
         param(
                 [object[]]$fileObj
                )

            $storageAccountName = "XXX"

            $tableName="XXX"

            # Get the storage key for the storage account
            $StorageAccountKey = "XXX"

            # Get a storage context
            $ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

            foreach($fo in $fileObj){
             Write-Host $fo.filepath
             $csv = Import-CSV $fo.filepath
              $cArray=$fo.Cols.split(",")
        $table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $fo.tableName -Context $ctx -ErrorAction Ignore
              [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableBatchOperation]$batchOperation = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableBatchOperation

if($table)
{
Write-Host "table not null"
}
else
{
Write-Host "table is null"
}
if($table.CloudTable)
{
Write-Host "CloudTable not null"
}
else
{
Write-Host "CloudTable is null"
}

foreach($line in $csv)
                {

                Write-Host "$($line.partitionkey), $($line.rowKey)"
                $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $line.partitionkey, $line.rowKey 
                    foreach($c in $cArray){
                 Write-Host "$c,$($line.$c)"
                    $entity.Properties.Add($c,$line.$c)
             $batchOperation.Insert($entity)

                    }       
             }
if($batchOperation)
{
Write-Host "batchOperation not null"
}
else
{
Write-Host "batchOperation is null"
}
    $table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch($batchOperation)
            }
```

Comment: @MSFT, I have copied your script and run the script by calling the parameters via argument task in powershell like   :::-fileObj @(@{"filepath"="$(build.sourcesdirectory)\DevOps\Deployment_Scripts\TestTable1.csv";"Cols"='Label_Value '},@{"filepath"="$(build.sourcesdirectory)\DevOps\Deployment_Scripts\TestTable2.csv";"Cols"='Label_Value ,Lable_cost'}) ..I will keep my log in onedrive location: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhn2jazDEmfRqV6yn  Please check and let me know what change I need to as it is throwing the error saying that:All entities in a given batch must have the same partition key

Comment: Forget about the above error:This I am running only one file by passing arguments like this: -fileObj @(@{"filepath"="$(build.sourcesdirectory)\DevOps\Deployment_Scripts\sampletable.csv";"Cols"='PartitionKey ,RowKey,Label_Usage,Label_Value,Usage_Location'})   and the error and sampletable.csv file I have kept in my one drive location.Please check that csv file and please check your script which you suggested and error log file.   Onedrive link : https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhwD2ArzyIVL9LBAg

Comment: Do you change the value of $storageAccountName, $tableName, $StorageAccountKey? Set syetem.debug to true, then queue build and share the log on the OneDrive. On the other hand, I move $table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch($batchOperation) code out of foreach($line in $csv) code.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhwMRTaHB7gU_X43Q  Please look at this logs attached with system.debug set=true before the update and after the update of your code I have run.As per the above updated code I have run the build still its throwing error and I have attached that log as well in one drive.Please help me..

Comment: Try to check object is null or not, check the updated code.

Comment: @MSFT, Now its still throwing error.Please check the log file updated in one drive. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhwRIdmgDp25rs6vV .

Comment: Can you call $table.CloudTable.Execute to save a entity? (previous code)

Comment: I have updated the same script whatever you have given and shared the log in one drive.By the way, $table.CloudTable.Execute function is already there in the script which you have given right.So where can I call,please update the code if possible?

Comment: Try to insert/update a record with batch way and check the result. (Create a new cvs file with a entity)

Comment: @MSFT, I couldn't able to understand,I have tried with another testtable1.csv file and executed the script but its still  throwing the below error.   2017-11-09T03:53:31.8180243Z en, AS_CLEAR
2017-11-09T03:53:31.8180243Z PartitionKey ,
2017-11-09T03:53:31.8210225Z ##[error]Exception calling "Insert" with "1" argument(s): "All entities in a given batch must have the same partition key."
At D:\a\1\s\DeploymentScripts\insert_replace_entities.ps1:47 char:14
+              $batchOperation.Insert($entity)

Comment: I am not understanding at this situation what I can do to complete this work as this is taking very long time for us.Even you helped me a lot ,we can't accomplish this task.Please try to test from your end and share me the script again.I hope you understand.

Comment: Does testtable1.csv just contain a record? `partitionkey,rowKey,Col1,Col2,Col3
p1,r1,one,two,three` (a record: p1, r1,one,two,three)

Comment: It contains many records as like languagetranslations.csv file which I shared in one drive.

Comment: Try it with a records and check the result.

Comment: Error is: 2017-11-09T03:53:31.8120228Z ##[error]Exception calling "Insert" with "1" argument(s): "All entities in a given batch must have the same partition key."
At D:\a\1\s\DeploymentScripts\insert_replace_entities.ps1:47 char:14
+              $batchOperation.Insert($entity)
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Comment: I tried with testtable1.csv but still it throwing the error.I just updated the error log file and Testtable1.csv file in One drive.Please check those files..   https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhwhAfDKephJtlmMQ

Comment: Tell me which script I can run so that it should not fail.Currently we can try with languagetranslations.csv file .If it successfully deployed the entities then we'll add 2 to 3 entries in the same csv file and try to deploy then we'll make sure the update has been doing well of csv entries into table storage.

Comment: There is record with `uk` partition key in TestTable1.csv, remove it and try again.

Comment: @MSFT, Now its throwing error .I have commented the complete error in the below 4 comments: table not null
CloudTable not null
eu, AS_rows
PartitionKey ,
RowKey,AS_rows
Label_Value,com
en, AS_CANCEL
PartitionKey ,
Exception calling "Insert" with "1" argument(s): "All entities in a given batch must have the same partition key."
RowKey,AS_CANCEL
Exception calling "Insert" with "1" argument(s): "All entities in a given batch must have the same partition key."
Label_Value,Cancel
At D:\a\1\s\DevOps\Deployment_Scripts\insert_replace_entities.ps1:47 char:14
en, AS_CLEAR
PartitionKey ,

Comment: Exception calling "Insert" with "1" argument(s): "All entities in a given batch must have the same partition key."
RowKey,AS_CLEAR
Exception calling "Insert" with "1" argument(s): "All entities in a given batch must have the same partition key."
Label_Value,Clear
Exception calling "Insert" with "1" argument(s): "All entities in a given batch must have the same partition key."
en, AS_COLUMNS
PartitionKey ,
Exception calling "Insert" with "1" argument(s): "All entities in a given batch must have the same partition key."
RowKey,AS_COLUMNS

Comment: Exception calling "Insert" with "1" argument(s): "All entities in a given batch must have the same partition key."
Label_Value,Columns
Exception calling "Insert" with "1" argument(s): "All entities in a given batch must have the same partition key."
en, AS_rows

Comment: At D:\a\1\s\DevOps\Deployment_Scripts\insert_replace_entities.ps1:47 char:14
PartitionKey ,
+ $batchOperation.Insert($entity)
RowKey,AS_rows
Label_Value,Apply
eu, AS_CLEAR
PartitionKey ,
RowKey,AS_CLEAR
Label_Value,rows
eu, AS_COLUMNS
PartitionKey ,
RowKey,AS_COLUMNS
Label_Value,start
batchOperation not null
Exception calling "ExecuteBatch" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Process completed with exit code 0 and had 12 error(s) written to the error stream.

Comment: What's the data in TestTable1.csv?

Comment: PartitionKey,RowKey,Label_Value
eu,AS_rows,com
en,AS_CANCEL,Cancel
en,AS_CLEAR,Clear
en,AS_COLUMNS,Columns
en,AS_rows,Apply
eu,AS_CLEAR,rows
eu,AS_COLUMNS,start

Comment: currently we can try with one table that is sampletable.csv file..We can hold the multiple tables deployment.Let's work on completing only one table.So that I will ask you in future for the multiple tables.Please help me on that.Currently As you have given the script for single table,I can insert all the sampletable entries into table storage but Its throwing the error when we try to deploy from 2nd time on wards,error is showing as conflict since the already existed data in the tables storage will not be updating and whatever the entries we added in csv file only updating into table storage.

Comment: Do you use `InsertOrReplace` method? (`$batchOperation.InsertOrReplace($entity)`)

Comment: In that script I am not using insertOrReplace operation.

Comment: I just updated the single table data deployment script which you have updated to me in the earlier thread.Please find this and help me out.The error log also I have uploaded in one drive.Kindly help me.  please find the script and log @ https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhwsBIf9X2nrfml6Y     Please update insertorreplace method in the shared script and it should not throw conflict error whenever I deploy new entries updated in csv file into table storage.

Comment: Just replace `Insert($entity)` to `InsertOrReplace($entity)`

Comment: @MSFT, Now its not throwing error for the existing entries,But Its not updating the entries say like,suppose I have entry en,Ak_update, Filter,population.Suppose I want to just modify this entry and update in the table storage but its not updating the existing entry in table storage its adding new entry for this.What should I do for this?

Comment: I could able to replace the entities.Thanks MSFT.I will let you know by tomorrow regarding this whether it is properly replacing or not.Thanks a lot MSFT.But regarding multiple tables deploy please check and update to me.

Comment: Seems the original issue of this thread hasn't been solved, what's the problem now? (You also can open a new thread for the detail issue)

Comment: @MSFT, As I said in our previous conversation regarding the multiple tables deployment issue,Its failing with errors.I have attached in the one drive and shared that link to you.Kindly check and let me know.Even I removed the UK entry as you said.Still failing ,I shared that log to you.See our previous conversation.

Comment: @MSFT, Do you have any idea about sonar cube setup in azure and connect through VSTS? if Yes,Please tell me I will open new thread and we can discuss over there..Please let me know.

Comment: You can share a new log, I don't know which log is newest. Regarding sonar cube issue, sorry I don't know.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to deal with this issue, you may open a new thread to let others to discuss the issue of batch operation.

Comment: @MSFT, The script is inserting and replacing the entities into table storage but its not updating the tables in table storage. The script @  https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AAEh_1faet-aXpg&id=5599285D52BD31F3%21907&cid=5599285D52BD31F3  this location is not deleting the rows in the table storage. Assume that,I have deleted 3 rows from the sampletable.csv file and trying to deploy using the script but it is not deleting those 3 rows in the table storage in azure its only inserting the new entities and replacing the entities.

Comment: Please help  me out how to change the script.It should update the table in table storage with the csv file entites.

Comment: It won't delete the entities that aren't existing in csv files, you can try to delete the table and recreate it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable?view=azure-dotnet (delete method)

Comment: ,I can delete the table and recreate it but that is not a good practice when I am doing the deployment into production.My leads recommended not to delete table since it is having thousands of rows .Everytime I can't delete and recreate the table.Please suggest any other way.Is there any update method available .If yes,please share me the script.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, you may open a new thread for this issue, maybe others  have the solution.